# Creating a Custom Scalable Slider - Process

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, scroll, scrollview

I'm been working on a UI widget for a couple of days and wrestled for most of it with a problem that on the surface seemed so trivial!

The task was to implement a time-line that could be zoom horizontally. Simple!

Wherever the mouse sits horizontally along the timeline should hold the line where it is when zooming and the time-line should zoom away from that point. Still, relatively simple on the surface!

The tricky part, I found, was juggling the length of the line and values of the 'timeline' as it zoomed against its relative 'pixel' values in the widget AND updating a scroll bar relative to any zooming and offsetting taking place.

This image illustrates the task:

Image overview of problem

[image]

The implementation was in Qt AND C++, however the challenge and my question are more about the process of tackling the problem. (Excuse my incorrect tags).

My question is:
(A) How would you break down this problem to come to with a solution and implementation.
(B) How would you approach 'learning' the steps to solve this and similar problems.

Thanks,

If i can clarify the problem further let me know (perhaps communicating the problem is the problem :) )

Comment: Do you want to change the width of a horizontal slide without changing his scale ?

Comment: Isn't it just about setting the range in the event handler and the step if you want to change the step, too? If so, it is just one method to implement, isn't it?

Comment: @iKiWiXz - What do you mean by a 'horizontal slide'?

Comment: A slide**r** that is horizontal (and not vertical).

Comment: @Ipapp - It may be that straight forward... how would you approach implementing this method? I swear it's got to be simple on face value!

Comment: @iKiWiXz - If by that you mean the scrollbar - Its pagestep changes as you zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reimplement the "zoom event" and calculate the new ranges and single step.

```
class ZoomSlider : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit ZoomSlider(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QSlider(parent) {}

    protected:
        void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
        {
            // Calculate x, y and z from event
            setRange(x, y);
            setSingleStep(z);
        }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ipapp, My current implementation extends QWidget. It has a custom paintEvent for drawing the line and its ticks, where the placement of and distance between ticks changes to give the impression of the timeline scrolling through the 'viewer' (black box of image in original post) when zooming or moving the scroll bar. Are you suggesting it is do-able using a QSlider?

Comment: @cdevelop: perhaps I did not understand your question. :) Why did you implement your own slider? What was wrong with QSlider + event handling?

Comment: Based on my limited Qt experience I opted for custom. Would you approach allow for the visual effect i illustrated?

Comment: @cdevelop: I do not know what you mean by ticks and their placement, but I cannot see the problem with my approach yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your slider has width `W` and current range is `[w1, w2]`, being the mouse in position `wm` given `w1 <= wm <= w2`.

Given that you want to zoom in/out by a percent of `10%` each.

```
#define ZOOM_RATIO 0.1
```

If you zoom in, new range `[i1,i2]` is smaller, so `i1>w1` and `i2<w2`:

```
i1 = wm - ( wm - w1 ) * ( 1.0 - ZOOM_RATIO );
i2 = wm - ( wm - w2 ) * ( 1.0 - ZOOM_RATIO );
```

When you zoom out:

```
i1 = wm - ( wm - w1 ) * ( 1.0 + ZOOM_RATIO );
i2 = wm - ( wm - w2 ) * ( 1.0 + ZOOM_RATIO );
```

After that, you need to check the validity of the new range: i.e. crop the range to be inside `[0, wmax]`.

Be sure that you use `double` for `wm, w1, w2, i1, i2`. Or at least, that you convert to double before doing the computations.